# Android Glide SimpleTarget onLoadFailed Exceptions

Tags: android, android-glide, socket-timeout-exception

I am using `Glide` as the image loading lib within my project as I am very happy with it's memory performance. However, when I download images as bitmaps using simpletarget, I do get failures to load the image.

```
 Glide.with(this).load(Utils_.getInstance_(application).getGlideURLWithHeaders(WebServices.URL_PREFIX + WebServices.ENDPOINT_GET_PICTURE_FROM_MATCH_USING_IDS + "/" + imageIds.get(0)))asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(targetOne);
```

I have come across a bunch of exceptions while downloading. I logged them and I want to eliminate occurrences of these as much as possible.

1. Exception :

   > Problem decoding into existing bitmap
2. Exception :

   > java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
3. Exception :

   > javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5742c778: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

I think the read timeout can probably be fixed by increasing the timeout by configuring `OkHttp`. I do not know how to set this up with `Glide` though.

My question is **how to I get rid of these image load errors as far as possible?**

Answer (score 0):

You can customize timeouts with OkHttp. See https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/432.